# Error: Cannot find module 'js/components/customer' from 'js/app.js'

Tags: vue.js, elixir, axios, phoenix-framework

my Vue component is not showing in the browser, `import customer from "./components/customer"` is giving me an error

I'm using:
- Phoenix 1.3
- Node v8.14.0

Bellow is my code

**assets/js/apps.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import "axios";
import "./socket"; // To be used later

import customer from "./components/customer"; // this is the line that brings the error message
Vue.component("customer", customer);

new Vue({}).$mount("#takso-app");
```

**lib/myApp/templates/pages/index.html.eex**

```
<div id="takso-app" style="border:solid red 2px">
  <customer></customer>
</div>
```

**assets/js/components/customer.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder = "address" v-model="address">
    </div>
    <div>
    <textarea class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#f4f7ff" rows="4" v-model="messages"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            address: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitBookingRequest: function() {
            axios.post("/api/bookings",
                {address: this.address})
                .then(response => {
                    this.messages = response.data.msg;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

I'm expecting my 2 input(address and message) should be visible in index.html.eex

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/130

change your /project-directory/webpack.config.js to following setting (just add extensions)

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},
```

Comment: the file webpack.config.js is not present in my project-directory. I think this resolution was applicable for phoenix 1.2 because there is no such a file in the entire project

Comment: I don't really know what that is but please see my other answer, it should be more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Phoenix, please refer to this advice - https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-graphql-vue-js-and-phoenix-1-3-part-2-the-frontend-716e8d980407

It explains that Phoenix doesn't use webpack but rather brunch.

The point I note that's different in their code when importing a Vue file, they explicitly add the .vue extension.

```
import customer from "./components/customer.vue";
```